# Problem of function using different conditions

Tags: functions

Let $f:{R^ + } \to R$

i- $f$ is strictly increasing

ii- $f\left( x \right) >  - {x^{ - 1}}$

iii-$f\left( x \right).f\left( {f\left( x \right) + {x^{ - 1}}} \right) = 1$

Then $f(1)$ can be equal to

(A) $\frac{{1 + {{0.5}^{0.5}}}}{2}$

(B) $\frac{{1 - {{0.5}^{0.5}}}}{2}$

(C) $\frac{{-1 - {{0.5}^{0.5}}}}{2}$

(D) $\frac{{-1 + {{0.5}^{0.5}}}}{2}$

My approach is as follow $x>0$

$f\left( x \right) + {x^{ - 1}} = g\left( x \right)$

$f\left( {g\left( x \right)} \right) = \frac{1}{{f\left( x \right)}}$

How do we proceed further

Comment: At iii-, is that dot a multiplication?

Comment: I think the question is incorrect. Have a look at my solution. https://imgur.com/HLARGCm

Comment: Equation are correct, I cross checked it with main problem

Comment: I mean answer choices